# RE: MVC5 C# current datetime query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, model-view-controller

I'm trying to get my posts to have a preset datetime field but when I go to edit my posts they are set to `01/01/2015 00:00` whereas i'd rather have them be automated to be like `14/07/2015 13:53` (or whatever the current datetime is). I thought adding a line above my datetime property like `[DateTime.current]` or something along those lines might work but I've not been successful yet.

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
    public int ThreadID { get; set; }
    public string PostTitle { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostDateTime { get; set; }
    public string PostBody { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your model, you could use the default constructor.

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
    public int ThreadID { get; set; }
    public string PostTitle { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostDateTime { get; set; }
    public string PostBody { get; set; }

    public Post()
    {
       PostDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Model binding occurs after the model has been created, so it won't affect MVC.

Comment: Don't forget about time zones if your app is an international

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a constructor to your Post class and pass the initial value you want your post to be initialized with ?

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
    public int ThreadID { get; set; }
    public string PostTitle { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostDateTime { get; set; }
    public string PostBody { get; set; }

    public Post( DateTime initialValue)
    {
         PostDateTime = initialValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the default `DateTime` that you would like in the constructor

```
public class Post
{
    public Post()
    {
        PostDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
    public int ThreadID { get; set; }
    public string PostTitle { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostDateTime { get; set; }
    public string PostBody { get; set; }
}
```

When this model is bound on the server side from values submitted by the client side, a `Post` instance will be created with a `PostDateTime` value as set in the constructor, but then this value will be overridden by the model binding process and set to the value submitted by the client, since `PostDateTime` is a property with a public setter.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses! works like a charm now :D